# Handle an event raised from background thread

Tags: events, c#-4.0, multithreading

I developed a class (in C#) for sending and receiving messages over network. It creates a new thread (listener thread) which waits till a new message arrives then raises an event. 
The problem is the event is raised in the listener thread and when I want to use this class in a wpf application, a run-time error occurs trying to handle the event
The error is:The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Is there any proper way to deal with this situation when the event raises in the mentioned class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to be on the UI thread to update UI objects. You can use the window's Dispatcher to execute code there:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    // Code that updates UI here
}));
```

Comment: Thanks I know this one, is there anyway which i can raise the event in the main thread from the class itself, i mean i want the user of the class (wpf) to be able to handle the event like other events

Comment: There's three things about an event: What thread it's raised on, the sender object and the event args. You can give whatever sender and event args you want and you can trigger the event inside the dispatcher method if you want it to be raised on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

BackgroundWorker explicitly supports marshaling to the UI thread.  You have to use it though, call its ReportProgress() method.  While optimized for reporting progress, you don't *have* to use it for that.  There's an overload that accepts an object, you can pass anything you want.  The event handler gets it as the e.UserState value.  From there, you could use that object directly or use it to re-raise another set of events.

Do beware thread-safety requirements for that object.  The worker keeps running and is *not* in any way synchronized with the execution of the ProgressChanged event handler.  So it should no longer update the object.  Best to create a new instance of it after calling ReportProgress().